# Redirecting to WWW domain if site is opened with HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, web, https

I want to redirect my site to https://www.domain.com  if someone opens the site with HTTPS.

Basically, if someone opens the site with  then it should redirect to .

i DONOT want to redirect to HTTPS if a vistior opens the site with HTTP, it should work as it is.

I have tried with these codes :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule .? http://www.domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule .? http://www.domain.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But its not working. Can anyone guide me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear. If you want to redirect from https to http://www , you can use :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule .? http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or if actually want to redirect from non-www to www, you can use :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|offs
RewriteRule .? http%1://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear, Let me try to clarify.  I want to redirect within  HTTPS only.  For example, if i opens the URL as  HTTPS://DOMAIN.COM then it should be redirect with WWW as HTTPS://WWW.DOMAIN.COM.   I DONOT want to put these conditions if someone opens the URL with HTTP

Comment: Thanks, i will check and let you know.